# Filter column table 1 and get results from table 2 by matching with another field

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**Setup:**

```
#---------#     #---------#
# table 1 #     # table 2 #
#---------#     #---------#
#ID A    *#  |--#ID B    *#
#ID B    *#--|  #DATA X  *#
#DATA Z   #     #DATA Y   #
#---------#     #---------#
```

(*) = primary key

**Wanted result:**

Filter on "ID A" and get all data from table 2 with "ID B"

*example:*

*Table 1*

```
ID A | ID B | DATA Z
  1     2       z1
  1     3       z2
  2     5       z5
```

*Table 2:*

```
ID B | DATA X | DATA Y |
  2      xy      yx
  3      x1      y1
  3      x2      y2
  4      x4      y4
```

*filter on ID A as '1', result:*

```
ID A | ID B | DATA X | DATA Y
  1     2       xy       yx
  1     3       x1       y1
  1     3       x2       y2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join the two tables by ID B and filter on Table1:

```
SELECT table1.idA,
       table2.*
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2
    ON table1.idB = table2.idB
 WHERE table1.idA = 1;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No results when I use an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Hm...according to your sample data the query above works fine, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e48995/1

Comment: Strange idd, the result is as asked, I must say, I am testing the SQL commands via an accessdb before putting it on mysql, that could be the problem here, because a "JOIN" command (<> "INNER JOIN") isn't accepted here. I'll test this on mysql and get back to you :) Thx for the reply